# SSRS Tablix blank row on top

Tags: reporting-services

My SSRS tablix has a extra row on top which I never added. My dataset contains only one column with two rows: Month-YY, Count. Not sure why this extra row is apprearing on top. Can someone please help?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The half double thick line on the left side of your table makes it look like your table may be nested inside of something like a rectangle.

Comment: Agreed to Daniel.